# VSCode remote containers - M1 ver Win11

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, remote-containers

My Win11 computer's VSCode for remote containers shows the green "Open in Remote Window" in the UI but my Mac M1 doesn't. Both are running docker and both took the latest updates. Is there a reason Mac M1 UI is different now or is this a bug?

[image]

The following image is from the M1 showing: docker desktop running, project running in dev container - see the container's terminal, and the version of vscode.

[image]

Comment: This might be an issue just for your Mac, as everything works on mine. Very likely you need to report to VS Code team following https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq#_questions-or-feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install the remote extension pack

You can get it from the extensions tab in vscode:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack

Then make sure it is enabled (from the extensions tab). If it is installed and not shown, right click anywhere on the bottom bar and make sure `remote hosts` is checked.

[image]

Comment: That has been installed and dev containers in VSCode has been working for a very long time. Only the green thing in the status bar went away. See screenshot added to description.

Comment: I updated the answer, hopefully ,it solves your problem

Comment: The bottom bar was the fix - thank  you so much!